# actionscript2 loadMovie() taking too long time to load external file

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am trying to load external .swf files in existing .swf file using the function loadMovie().

I am using a setInterval(loadWait, 100) function that runs every 100 ms to check if the load is complete. It is taking too long time to load even a small file (200 kb). It appears that it is taking around 2 secs even to start loading the file (getBytesTotal() is -1)

Can anyone please help me figure out this issue?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a MovieClipLoader instance to load swfs into your current scene

```
mcl = new MovieClipLoader();
mcl.onLoadError = function(targMC:MovieClip, error:String, status:Number):Void {
 trace("Error " + status + ": Loading operation for " + targMC + " failed due to: " + error);
}
mcl.loadClip("some.swf", myMC);
```